# LINQ Group By Multiple parameters or fields

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have flights collection.
I want to use "GroupBy" in this collection.

GroupBy works for one field.This is works for MarketingAirline field.

```
MYFLIGHTS.GroupBy(g => g.DepartureFlights.First().Segments.First().MarketingAirline);
```

But I want to use GroupBy with two fields.

I try this

```
    MYFLIGHTS.GroupBy(g => g.DepartureFlights.First().Segments.First().MarketingAirline 
&& g.DepartureFlights.FirstOrDefault().StopCount.ToString());
```

but it give error

Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an anonymous object and use it for grouping:

```
MYFLIGHTS.GroupBy(g => 
    new { 
        g.DepartureFlights.First().Segments.First().MarketingAirline, 
        g.DepartureFlights.FirstOrDefault().StopCount
    });
```

Comment: Wow did not know that, very useful ! Thanks a lot

Comment: thank you @dotnetom ..instead of .First() i want to get all.I use any or all but it give error.what should I do?